# Crystal pass variable by reference or value

Tags: crystal-lang

How do I choose how to pass a variable by value or reference using Crystal ?

Exemple : I would like to pass a Struct by reference and not by Value ( the documentation explains that it is passed by Value while classes are passed by reference ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't choose. You just need to keep in mind that object which is a `Value` passed by value, other objects passed by reference.

`Struct` is a `Value` and passed by value. You should prefer using structs for immutable data types. However, mutable structs are still allowed in Crystal and actually [this example](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Struct.html) demonstrates how to mutate it using a method. In short:

```
struct Mutable
  property value

  def initialize(@value : Int32)
  end
end

def change(mutable)
  mutable.value = 2
  mutable
end

mut = Mutable.new 1
mut = change(mut)
mut.value # => 2
```

Comment: Using pointers outside bindings or special performance optimizations certainly isn't best practice.

Comment: @JonneHaß thanks, added your comment to the answer in bold

Comment: It's not just bad practice but actually unsafe code!

Comment: I think that mentioning unsafe pointers in this example is a bad idea. You'd be better off introducing a `class` wrapper which forwards all calls to the inner `Value` type.

Comment: @RX14 honestly, i think this is a problem of the language, not the example itself. OP is free to choose the way to code and  is responsible for it. But I am okay to remove it from the answer.

Comment: Mutable struct has an issue here https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4933